# Entity Framework - I can't insert enties where i have association One - to - Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity, sql-server-ce

I just make desktop application with Entity Framework 4.0 and i using Sql server Compact 3.5. I have few Entities in my example Driver and Bus. Every Driver was assigned to one Bus, but every Bus can be assigned to many Drivers. Ok let's see how i build my entites.

Driver have Id (PK, non-nullable, int32, StoreGeneratedPatter - Identity), FirstName (non-nullable, string), LastName (non-nullable, string), Addres (non-nullable, string), Age (non-nullable, int32)
Bus have Id (PK, non-nullable, int32, StoreGeneratedPatter - NONE!), IsBig non-nullable, boolean), Mark (non-nullable, string), Year(non-nllabble, string)

Now the problem is that i make and add some bus to BusSet but i can't do this with Driver.. why? Maybe because of

> StoreGeneratedPattern

?

Here is code:

```
        Bus aut = new Bus() { Id = 403, IsBig = true, Mark = "Solaris", Year = "1999" };
        Driver kier = new Driver() { FirstName = "s", LastName = "sdasd", Addres = "sdsa", Age = 50 };

using (KierowcyContext db = new KierowcyContext))
{
                            db.BusSet.AddObject(aut);
                            db.Drivers.AddObject(kier);
                            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: "i can't do this": what does this mean? Exception?

Comment: I think SQL Compact 3.5 doesn't support store generated keys.

Comment: Yeah, Exception but exception message is sooo long and useless